# What does 'Surge' mean in Destiny?

Tags: destiny

While playing destiny I sometimes see

> Surge 0:05

and it counts down (there are some other messages too).

What does it mean?

Answer (score 6):

Surge is a Voidwalker's second-tier melee skill.

It increases "weapon and movement speed," according to the tooltip. While I can confirm that it is a pretty significant movement speed increase, I haven't noticed any significant change to my weapons while under its effect.

Answer (score 3):

"Surge" is for a skill with the Warlock class as I have seen it on my friend's Warlock character. The details read: "Damaging an enemy with Energy Drain increases weapon and movement speed"

I have seen a similar countdown for "Chain of Woe" with my Hunter character.

Answer (score 0):

Surge buffs you movement speed and reload speed. Surge can only be used by voidwalkers. It's the second upgrade for Energy Drain

I hope this helped.